# linkWithCredential and Flutter Web with Apple

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have a use case where a user, on Flutter Web, needs to link an Apple auth with their existing account, and the email may not match.

However, the only available method for Flutter Web Apple Authentication is `signInWithPopUp`. If the user's apple email is different from the User firebase account email, a new firebase account is created, and a user is returned, short circuiting the process of linking, this creates a new account in firebase, and I'm unable to `linkWithCredential`.

My method to try to link accounts is as follows:

```
  Future<String> linkWithAppleWeb() async {
    try {
      final User user = _auth.currentUser!;
      final provider = OAuthProvider("apple.com")
        ..addScope('email')
        ..addScope('name');
      await _auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then((appleCredential) async {
        final authCredential = appleCredential.credential;

        await user.linkWithCredential(authCredential!).then((result) {
          DatabaseService().updateUserSocialAuth(user.uid, 'apple');
          return 'Success';
        }).catchError((e) {
          return 'Error: $e';
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      return 'Error: $e';
    }
    return 'Success';
  }
```

As you would expect, my project starts with Streaming a User Object, [and when the pop up signs in, it returns the new user](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth_platform_interface/latest/firebase_auth_platform_interface/FirebaseAuthPlatform/signInWithPopup.html), which rebuilds the entire project.  Is there a way to authenticate an apple user without returning a new user?  I can link a google or phone authorization method fine. It's apple that is problematic. I don't fully understand why Google doesn't break in the same way, other than Firebase put in the work to ensure the functionality of linking for `GoogleSignIn().signIn()` I'm not using other social auth methods, and I don't use password/email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is not documented in the [Flutter Fire Docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/social), but works perfectly:

```
  Future<String> linkWithAppleWeb() async {
    try {
      final User user = _auth.currentUser!;
      final provider = OAuthProvider("apple.com")
        ..addScope('email')
        ..addScope('name');
      await user.linkWithPopup(provider).then((result) {
        DatabaseService().updateUserSocialAuth(user.uid, 'apple');
        return 'Success';
      }).catchError((e) {
        return 'Error: $e';
      });
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('auth linkWithGoogle error: ${e.toString()}');
      return 'Error: $e';
    }
    return 'Success';
  }
```